# data validation javascript

Tags: javascript, validation

I have some problems on my form (validation.) They don't give any error when the datas are not given. How can I fix this problem? This is just some part of my code. For letter, numbers and e-mail types, it works perfectly. Thank you for your help.

```
function onFormSubmit(form_element){
    var checked = 0;
    if (form_element.gender[0].checked == false && form_element.gender[1].checked == false){
        alert("Please choose your Gender:Male of Female");
        return false;
    }

    if (form_element.make.selectedIndex == 0){
        alert("Please select your rating interval.");
        form_element.make.focus();
        return false;
    }

    if (form_element.click.checked == false){
        alert("Please confirm your registration!");
        false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

html

```
<form class="contact_form" action="" method="post" name="contact_form" onsubmit="return onFormSubmit(this)">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <h2>Sign-Up Form</h2>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="Male">Male:</label>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="m" /> &nbsp; Female:<input type="radio" name="gender" value="f" />
            <br />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="National Rating">National Rating:</label>
            <select name="make">
                  <option selected>-- SELECT --</option>
                  <option> Below 1200 </option>
                  <option> 1200 - 1500 </option>
                  <option> 1500 - 1800 </option>
                  <option> 1800 - 2100 </option>
                  <option> Above 2100 </option>
            </select><br />
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="click" value="regist"> I confirm my registration.
            <br />
        </li>
        <li>
            <button class="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
<div id="error_message" style="color:#ff0000;"></div>
```

Comment: I tire of saying this to people, but **please** indent your code **properly** so it's readable to other human beings. Your code is currently a right mess and it's hardly possible to follow where one scope ends and another begins

Comment: edited indentations, you're welcome. but i see something wrong with the code itself

Comment: How can I indent the code properly? Could you please help?

Answer (score 1):

In this test:

```
> if (form_element.click.checked == false){
>           alert("Please confirm your registration!");
>           false;
```

you left out a `return`.

Comment: I tried them with return and without return several times. It doesn't work. Moreover, they say my code is like mess. Which part is like mess? HTML or javascript? And how can I write it properly? I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

From your functions name I would say you call it during onSubmit?
Most Browsers don't show alerts during onSubmit.
I suggest to first do validation and then submit the data.

Comment: Where did you get that idea? All browsers I know of allow alerts to be shown from a submit listener.

Answer (score 0):

just attach to the `onclick` event and it works:

```
<form class="contact_form" action="" method="post" name="contact_form" onclick="onFormSubmit">
```

Comment: instead of onsubmit="return onFormSubmit(this) ?